# pyw file opens visual studio instead of running the program

Tags: python, visual-studio, pythonw

So I have a .pyw file, default program to open it is pythonw.exe, but instead when I run it it opens visual studio. Maybe a behind the scenes error? 
Program was set up in the task scheduler with highest permissions to access hosts file in windows. The test path works fine.

```
import time
from datetime import datetime as dt



# Temporary hosts path to test
hosts_temp = r"C:\Users\letto4135\Desktop\python_programs\web_block\hosts"

# Hosts path in windows
hosts_path = r'C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts'

# Redirect to this IP
redirect = "127.0.0.1"

# List of Websites to block
website_list = ['www.facebook.com','facebook.com']



while True:
    # If between time, block sites
    if dt(dt.now().year,dt.now().month,dt.now().day,8) < dt.now() < dt(dt.now().year, dt.now().month,dt.now().day,16):
        with open(hosts_path,'r+') as file:
            content = file.read()
            for site in website_list:
                if site in content:
                    pass
                else:
                    file.write('\n' + redirect + ' ' + site)
    # If not between time allow sites
    else:
        with open(hosts_path, 'r+') as file:
            content = file.readlines()
            file.seek(0)
            for line in content:
                if not any (website in line for website in website_list):
                    file.write(line)
            file.truncate()
    # Run every ("") seconds.
    time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the Task scheduler.
If this ever happens to you, 
under actions tab in program/script box put full path to pythonw.exe,
then in Add arguments box put the full path to your program.